# C++ sfml receives close event just after window opens

Tags: c++, xcode, sfml

I am trying to follow a SFML tutorial from this [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kAbkFY6lwAY), however, for some reason my application seems to be caling the close event as soon as my program enters into the event loop.

Here is my code.

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <iostream>

// Here is a small helper for you ! Have a look.
#include "ResourcePath.hpp"

int main()
{
sf::RenderWindow Window(sf::VideoMode(500,400),"SFML tutorial");
/* Or we can do this
 * sf::RenderWindow Window
 * Window.create (sf::VideoMode(800,600),"SFML tutorial");
 */

//Game loop
while(Window.isOpen())
{
    sf::Event Event;
    while(Window.pollEvent(Event));
    {
        if(Event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
        {
            Window.close();
            std::cout << "Close" << std::endl;

        }
    }
}

return 0;
```

}

For some reason as soon as my program enters the event loop it receives a sf::Event::Closed event. I have done some research and this is not because the window is too big for my screen. 
To fix my issue I have had to ad a int variable `canClose` to 0 then modify the event loop to this.

```
if(Event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
{
    if(canClose == 1)
    {
        Window.close();
    } else {
        canClose = 1;
    }
}
```

After I do this the window now opens and runs as expected.

P.S this is made using xcode and the SFML template.

**Edit:** 
**Just made a new xcode SFML project and removed some code in it to make a empty window and it seems to whork. Code looks exactly the same. This seams strange because it is exactly the same code.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what i have seen, do not use an if statement for checking events, use a switch statement. Also Use a `while(window.isOpen())` when trying to poll events

Have you read through the tutorials on http://www.sfml-dev.org ? Because i can guarantee that it is the best source for learning sfml. Use it before using another source.

Comment: The tutorial I am using has now said to use switch statements. They probably used if statements so it was easy for us to get used to. I also prefer leaning via videos because if I am reading the docs I tend to get distracted and board. Thanks for the tip though!

Comment: @aPyDeveloper Im in the same boat as you. Learning from videos is what i prefer. But if you ever wanna be successful, you will need to read source and documentation. They way i did this is to go into full screen and every time you feel distracted try and refocus your self. Give your self some sort of motivation as well.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Will try next time.

Answer (score -1):

Your problem is that you declared the variable Event Event type, you have to change the name of the variable to lowercase.

in this way

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <iostream>

// Here is a small helper for you ! Have a look.
#include "ResourcePath.hpp"

int main()
{
sf::RenderWindow Window(sf::VideoMode(500,400),"SFML tutorial");
/* Or we can do this
* sf::RenderWindow Window
* Window.create (sf::VideoMode(800,600),"SFML tutorial");
*/

//Game loop
while(Window.isOpen())
{
sf::Event event;
while(Window.pollEvent(event));
{
    if(event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
    {
        Window.close();
        std::cout << "Close" << std::endl;

    }
}
} 

return 0;
```

that way you will not have any problems

Comment: Tried this and it does not work. Do you know what else could cause the issue?